# python splitting numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, split

I am working with a list of lists and I am using coordinates to work my way through the lists.
After starting at coordinates 0,0 my list for neighboring nodes looks like this:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Next I choose the first node so it looks like:

```
(0, 1)
```

I want to be able to split up the first number from the second and assign them to i and j so I can keep iterating through the loop. Is there any way to accomplish this? I know of for x in list but that loops through each item which is (0,1) and not each individual number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
In [45]: lis=[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]

In [46]: for i,j in lis:
   ....:     print i,j
   ....:     
0 1
1 0
1 1
```